# Ubuntu stuck on boot on mac mini after the upgrade

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, updates

I have been using Ubuntu server 20.04 on a mac mini.

Today I have installed the pending updates.

After the updates it is stuck on apple logo.

Please help as my database server is running on it .

Comment: Hi. Try going back to older kernel. Try 5.8.

Comment: How , it is stuck on apple logo. Nothing is working .

Comment: If it won't boot past the Apple logo, try clearing the PRAM.  Press and hold Command+Option+P+R right after powering on until you hear the startup chimes again.  Try this at least 2 or 3 times.  Sounds like something is stuck in the PRAM.

Comment: No its not working , I tried reseting the PRAM. I think i need to reinstall my boot loader . Can someone guide how to reinstall the boot  loader as pressing SHIFT is not taking me to the GRUB menu.

Comment: Considering it is a mac mini

Comment: assuming you can boot from a live dvd or usb drive you could follow this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I would advise against using boot-repair as it f#@%s up the Mac EFI. My own Mac Mini runs 20.04 desktop and I learnt that the hard way durin initial install a year or so ago. So I assume you bypassed the T2 chip when you did your initial install? So if you are referring to an Ubuntu update that caused this then it must be the grub. So create a live USB and see if you can get in from there.